# Clear email input on click of 'Submit' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I went through every post I could find related to this matter but nothing worked for me.

I have a website where I use an embedded form from MailChimp. You enter your email and a new page/tab opens with the success message. The problem is that the email address added in the field is still there upon submission.

This is the form I am using:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<input type="email" value="Email" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>  
<input type="hidden" name="SIGNUP" id="SIGNUP" value="tgg_page" />
<div class="clear">
<input type="submit" value="ΣΤΕΙΛΤΕ ΤΟ ΔΩΡΟ ΜΟΥ!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button_link hover_fade large_button gift_button red">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

I tried adding this javascript code but it didn't work

```
<script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>

        function ClearAllControls() 
        {
              for (i=0; i<document.forms[0].length; i++)
              {
                    doc = document.forms[0].elements[i];
                    switch (doc.type) 
                    {
                        case "text" :
                                doc.value = "";
                                break;
                          case "checkbox" :
                                doc.checked = false;
                                break;    
                          case "radio" :
                                doc.checked = false;
                                break;                
                          case "select-one" :
                                doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].selected = false;
                                break;                      
                          case "select-multiple" :
                                while (doc.selectedIndex != -1) 
                                {
                                      indx = doc.selectedIndex;
                                      doc.options[indx].selected = false;
                                }
                                doc.selected = false;
                                break;

                          default :
                                break;
                    }
              }
        }

</script>
```

I have also came across the HTML and jquery Reset Button solutions, but it is not something I want to use.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that, just reset the form using `form.reset();`

So...

`document.forms[0].reset();`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Can you pls give me more information on how I should use this code? I am not familiar with js or jquery so it's difficult for me to undestand.

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to add something like `onsubmit="this.reset();"` to your form tags so it would look like `<form method="..." action="..." otherstuff="..." onsubmit="this.reset();">`

Comment: But I can't confirm as I don't know how mailchimp form works, you may have problems with the ajax if you do it that way.

Comment: It looks like I have. When I add onsubmit="this.reset();" it returns an error for invalid email address. So I guess it stops the info to be passed to mailchimp.